# Android 4.2.1 / 4.2.2 Notifications vibrate in silent mode

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-notifications, android-vibration

Prior to Android 4.2.1 the following code worked just fine

```
notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_RING;
notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT
        | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notificationManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION_SOUND, notification);
```

Vibration is done separately, depending on the state of a preference setting.

```
vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(vibr_pattern1, 0);
```

Now with Android 4.2.1+ there is always vibration even if the phone is set to silent (no vibration) and set to vibrate mode, even if the app settings for vibration are set to off.
Interestingly there is no vibration when the phone is in normal mode.

As mentioned, everything worked fine before 4.2.1.

Can someone help? What did google change here? Is it related to [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39592)?

Regards,
Andreas

Comment: Is the code in the post only for 'sound' notifications? Perhaps you can provide the code of the vibration notification?

Comment: Edited. Of course vibration is only used when requested by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
//vibration workaround for android 4.2.1+
notification.vibrate = new long[]{0,0};
//end workaround
```

I manually add "no vibration" and if the user chooses vibration it's done with an `Vibrator` object. If not, the code above keeps everything quiet. As mentioned before, this was not necessary before 4.2.1+

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. But for some one who is looking for answer. You can try this.

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    switch( audio.getRingerMode() ){
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        try {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            r.play();
            v.vibrate(500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
       break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
         v.vibrate(500);
       break;
    }
```